# Upgrading Instances in cloudformation stack with attached volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, upgrade, aws-cloudformation

For the sake of this discussion, I have a very simple cloudformation setup with 1 EC2 instance that has a volume attached to it. For the sake of data retention, the volume is not part of the stack, so that even when I destroy and rebuild the complete stack, the data would not be destroyed.

My problem is that when I create a new `ami` as a base image for my EC2 instance and upgrade my stack to roll out the new image, I get am understandable conflict.

The way that EC2 upgrades instances is that it creates the new one, then deletes the old one. But since the cloudformation script declares that the volume should be attached to the instance, the upgrade process fails on creating the upgraded instance, due to the volume not being available.

What is the best way to retain data between image upgrades? I've been searching for the right solution for days now, but with no luck. It would seem that there are many dodgy solutions out there where people are happy with manual tasks in the rollout/upgrade process. I would like to avoid all human errors by being able to fully automate the infrastructure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into using an AutoScalingGroup with a cluster size of 1 and then modifying the UpdatePolicy?  This may give you more fine grained control over how many instances would be in play at a given time and how they were updated. It would also help if you were able to post the critical parts of your template.

The other option is doing stack creates/updates with bash or Python where you programmatically attach/detach.

The only other way I can think of to do this is to set the AutoScalingGroup minSize and maxSize to zero (could be done with CLI), wait for the instance to spin down, and then run update with your new AMI (and the min/max back to 1) and that would bring them back online.

```
"ServerGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "AvailabilityZones" : {
      "Fn::If" : [
        "UseAllAvailabilityZones",
        { "Fn::GetAZs": "" },
        {"Ref" : "AvailabilityZones"}

    },
    "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
    "MinSize" : 1,
    "MaxSize" : 1,
    "DesiredCapacity" : 1,
    "LoadBalancerNames" : [ { "Ref" : "PublicElb" }, { "Ref" : "PrivateElb" } ],
    "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref" : "Subnets" }
  },
  "UpdatePolicy" : {
    "AutoScalingScheduledAction" : {
      "IgnoreUnmodifiedGroupSizeProperties" : "true"
    },
    "AutoScalingRollingUpdate" : {
      "MinInstancesInService" : "0",
      "MaxBatchSize" : "1"
    }
  }
}
```

I also found this project with seems to be doing some similar things with volumes.
https://github.com/thefactory/cloudformation-graphite/blob/master/graphite.json

Comment: Woah, this seems to be way over the top, but I guess until amazon starts supporting this kind of operation, there's no easy way around it. Thank you for the ideas and the example!

Comment: Let me know where you land.  It's an interesting problem.  While researching this I realized that I had neglected to re-establish drive mounts for one of my servers on reboot.  So your question kind of saved my tail in some respects.